# IntelliJ IDEA seems to be ignoring code formatting

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, google-style-guide, intellij-12

I've been attempting to get my Intellij IDEA to confirm to a google-like Java standard - however both imports and manual settings seem to be ignored.

Here's how my indentations are currently set:
[image: sceenshot]

However my code still formats at 4 spaces, and when I reformat it goes to 4 spaces as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is an old question, JFTR: The issue could be related to using .editorconfig file, which overrides IDE and project code-style settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the setting for your `GoogleStyle` scheme. But your project most likely doesn't use it. It's not enough to just select it in the combobox. You need to import this scheme into your project.

Click `Manage...` and `Copy to Project`, and it should work as expected.

Also, make sure you're setting language-spefic settings, so instead `Code Style` select `Code Style > Java`.

Comment: Hmmm, I've tried that - however even when I review that the indentation is 2, and then format, I get indented to 4 spaces.  Seems something else is missing.

Comment: You've probably set the generic indent size (`Code Style`). It is overriden by the more specific indent size. Look under `Code Style > Java`